# Is there a module to log errors in memory?

Tags: python, python-2.7, logging

So I would like to log errors in memory (I don't want to write any logfile) and access them later to display them in a bulk after the program execution. 
It would look like:

```
...
Program executing ...
...
Errors occured !
Error 1 : ...
Error 2 : ...
```

I am not asking how to do it myself but if some existing module is capable of that. I would like to use standard modules as much as possible.

Comment: Store the exceptions in a list and print them when you want. Doesn't work between executions.

Comment: What do you mean with 'log errors in memory'? You could put them in a variable like @msvalkon suggested

Comment: What is your execution environment? uwsgi?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You could pass a [StringIO](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stringio.html) buffer to a [StreamHandler](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.handlers.html#streamhandler) of the standard logging module. In Python2:

```
import logging, StringIO

print 'Setting up logging ...'
stream = StringIO.StringIO()
logger = logging.getLogger()
handler = logging.StreamHandler(stream)
logger.addHandler(handler)

print 'Starting main program ...'
logger.warning('This is serious')
logger.error('This is really bad')

print 'Finished main, printing log messages ...'
print stream.getvalue()
```

As commented by Hettomei, the imports should be changed slightly for Python3:

```
import logging, io

print('Setting up logging ...')
stream = io.StringIO()
logger = logging.getLogger()
handler = logging.StreamHandler(stream)
logger.addHandler(handler)

print('Starting main program ...')
logger.warning('This is serious')
logger.error('This is really bad')

print('Finished main, printing log messages ...')
print(stream.getvalue())
```

In both cases, you get the desired result:

```
Setting up logging ...
Starting main program ...
Finished main, printing log messages ...
This is serious
This is really bad
```

Comment: If using python3 you have to replace those 2 lines :
import io;     stream = io.StringIO();
Works very well thank you.